# Showing unwanted space on the right side of a page in mobile chrome browser but fine in mobile firefox browser

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

A page on my site is showing an unwanted white space on the right side in mobile, the page is showing fine in android Mozilla Firefox browser but the problem is occurring in android Google Chrome browser. All the other pages are fine. I can't find out where the problem is lying in this particular page. Following is the link of the page:

https://digifrizz.com/digifrizz-new/about.html

The screenshot is as follows:

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: can u plz move the head tag within the body tag.. it may be hope so!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because of you make `container` padding `0px`using class `px-0` remove this class with the `container` class at the place mentioned by me in following image. I am sure this will help.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I hope this will help to solve your problem what you are facing right now.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Its because this section has no padding from left and right
Please add 15px padding from left and right in this section